# Debug.Print fires differently in VBA Step vs. Run. Why?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an interface `IFoo` and a `Foo` class that implements `IFoo`. `Foo` has `PredelaredID = True`.

```
IFoo:
Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property
Public Property Get Number() As Long
End Property


Foo:
Implements IFoo
Private Type TFoo
    Name As String
    Number As Long
End Type
Private this As TFoo

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Initializing " & TypeName(Me)
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Terminating " & TypeName(Me)
End Sub

Private Property Get IFoo_Name() As String
    IFoo_Name = this.Name
End Property
Private Property Get IFoo_Number() As Long
    IFoo_Number = this.Number
End Property
Private Sub DoFoo(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Number As Long)
    Debug.Print "DoingFoo", Name, Number
End Sub

'Factory
Public Function Create(ByVal Name As String, Number As Long) As IFoo
    With New Foo
        .Name = Name
        .Number = Number
        Set Create = .Self
        DoFoo Name, Number
    End With
End Function
Public Property Get Self() As IFoo
    Set Self = Me
End Property
Public Property Let Name(ByVal RHS As String)
    this.Name = RHS
End Property
Public Property Let Number(ByVal RHS As Long)
    this.Number = RHS
End Property
```

The Calling Code:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim myFoo As IFoo
    With Foo
        Set myFoo = .Create("myFooName", 42)
    End With
    Set myFoo = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I run `Main` I get in the Immediate Pane:

```
Initializing Foo
Initializing Foo
DoingFoo      myFooName      42 
Terminating Foo
```

When I step through (F8) I get:

```
Initializing Foo
DoingFoo      myFooName      42 
Terminating Foo
```

Why do I get the extra "Initializing Foo" when using Run?

Comment: The question really is, why only one "Initializing Foo" when using F8. `With Foo` instantiates the predeclared instance, `.Create` instantiates another. Given the way you are creating instances, what was your reason to play with `PredelaredID`? Simply put `Public Function Create` in a module and make your `Foo` public-non-creatable.

Comment: Do you perform complete project reset between your tests? The predeclared `Foo` instance will persist across your tries unless the VBA project is reset, so on your second attempt `Foo` will not be created because it already exists, and you will only see one message for the instance created by `.Create`.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the comments. The "what was your reason to play with `PredeclaredID`" reason is to understand the mechanism and not real world. I am using the `PredeclaredID` technique described by Mathieu Guindon in a project and was not getting the results I expected. Hence the simplification to `Foo` to tease out my issue. I'll make sure to reset and retest. Thank you for your time and consideration.